# outlook.com web add-in | how to display add-in on top ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook.com

I working on building an add-In for outlook.com (web version). It perform some action on emails. Currently
it works with single email i.e. when you are reading an email, i click on the "..." menu and i can see my add-In there.

However i am facing 2 issues:

1. how to display add-on on the ribbon (see screenshot below)? is it possible? currently it is visible only in email read panel.
2. I want to perform the same task on multiple email selection i.e.user can select multiple emails and then click on my add-in (for this add-in needs to be present in ribbon i.e. question#1).

what I know so far is, "ExtensionPoint" is the property that defined where add-in will apear which currently can be set as MessageReadCommandSurface or MessageComposeCommandSurface but this display add-in on single email level

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can pin the add-in to Message window (quick actions) using

   ```
    settings -> Mail -> Customize actions -> Message Surface/Toolbar
   ```

   You can choose the surface (based on add-ins availability on that surface) to show the
   add-in individually. [Visit here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-on-the-web-8f2ce816-5df4-44a5-958c-f7f9d6dabdce) to find more.
2. Currently the feature of enabling add-ins on multiple selected mails is not there. We track
   Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there.
   Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.